# How to set Primeng P-tree selectionMode checkbox (Checked)true?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, primeng

I am displaying primeng P-tree SelectionMode checkbox of (parent and child nodes) datas, after selection of nodes ,  I am filtering the selection property to get the ids of selected nodes but On load of screen how can i set tree nodes checked true with the help of ids.

I am attaching the stackblitz url for reference :- https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-treeselection-demo-ewe5tq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Please help on these issue

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

With `[(selection)]="selectedModulePermissions"` we can give what is already selected. I'm sure you can think of a better way to pre-check what you want but for a simple demo this should do.

```js
  ngOnInit() {
    this.defaultSelected()
  }

  defaultSelected() {
    this.selectedModulePermissions.push(this.modulePagePermissions[1])
    this.selectedModulePermissions.push(this.modulePagePermissions[0].children[0])
  }
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-treeselection-demo-wuapns?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts